# Laravel Eager Loading not working properly as a DB query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am calling my transaction with 2 eloquent functions (`supplier` and `demander`), i'm logging the query, yet for some reason it's being totally mishandled.

```
 $transactionSegregated = Transaction::with([
            'demandCurrency',
            'supplier' => function($query){$query->where('is_test','=', 0);},
            'demander' => function($query){$query->where('is_test','=', 0);},
        ])
            ->where('date', '>=', $carbonDates['dateFrom'])
            ->where('date', '<=', $carbonDates['dateTo'])
            ->get();
```

Supplier (and demander) is just an eloquent join for Customer:

```
public function supplier(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'site_user1');
}
```

Here is the pertinent part of my simple query, where everything looks 100%. currently testing, so i'm setting Customer ID 21 with `is_test = 1` and it's still bringing that row, even though I am asking him to restrict it only to customers that are `is_test = 0`:

```
 array (
    'query' => 'select * from `currencies` where `currencies`.`id` in (?)',
    'bindings' =>
    array (
      0 => 27,
    ),
    'time' => 2.1800000000000002,
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    'query' => 'select * from `customers` where `customers`.`id` in (?) and `is_test` = ?',
    'bindings' =>
    array (
      0 => 21,
      1 => 0,
    ),
    'time' => 2.5299999999999998,
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    'query' => 'select * from `customers` where `customers`.`id` in (?) and `is_test` = ?',
    'bindings' =>
    array (
      0 => 21,
      1 => 0,
    ),
    'time' => 2.5699999999999998,
  ),
  4 =>
  array (
    'query' => 'select * from `requests` where `approved_at` >= ? and `approved_at` <= ? and `request_status` = ?',
    'bindings' =>
    array (
      0 =>
      Illuminate\Support\Carbon::__set_state(array(
         'date' => '2018-12-06 00:00:00.774876',
         'timezone_type' => 3,
         'timezone' => 'America/Dominica',
      )),
      1 =>
      Illuminate\Support\Carbon::__set_state(array(
         'date' => '2018-12-06 10:32:36.774951',
         'timezone_type' => 3,
         'timezone' => 'America/Dominica',
      )),
      2 => 2,
    ),
    'time' => 2.7200000000000002,
  ),
```

I am expecting this row not to return when `demander`'s or `supplier`'s has `is_test = 1`

Comment: What's the point in using a transaction here if only SELECTing from database? Also never saw this notion, maybe try one of the approaches described here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#database-transactions

Comment: @Sachem `Transaction` is the name of their model.

Comment: "it's still bringing that row": Do you mean the transaction? I think you are looking for `whereHas()`. https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir dammm :)

Comment: I just queried `whereHas` and it's horrible it's actually creating a `SELECT *` subquery, I solved my issue by creating a join on a specific FK, thus getting only the relevant relationals that exist.
Thanks anyways, i'll create an answer that would be proficient and optimal when I have the time. And please, do not recommend using `whereHas` **ever**, what a horrible construct.

Comment: Why is it horrible? Because of the subquery or because of the `SELECT *`?